# Snail species identification from the United Kingdom

Tags: species-identification, zoology, gastropod, snail

Can anybody identify the species of this snail?

From [this website](http://www.bnhs.co.uk/youngnats/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Garden-snail-and-slug-sheet.pdf), it looks like a Common Snail.

Could it be the dextral type of [*Cornu aspersum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornu_aspersum)?

These snails have been found in a garden, have survived a month on lettuce in a home environment, retreat in their shell sometimes. Their shell measures about 2 cm diameter.

[image]

Comment: To me it look like that your guess is correct, but I'm not an expert.

Answer (score -2):

This snail is ***Cornu aspersum*** its common name is garden snail, it belongs to **Helicidae** family click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornu_aspersum) for more information

[image]

Comment: Given that the OP thought this was the correct species but was unsure, good answers to this question *should explicitly* describe the characteristics or evidence that support that this is in fact the correct ID. Please [edit] your post to provide explicitly-stated evidence for why your ID is correct. Thank you.